# Is this mathematical statement?

Tags: fake-proofs, integers, formal-proofs, combinatorial-proofs

$\{\text{integers $n$ such that $n$ is even}\}$

It can be true/false so does that mean it's proposition/mathematical statement?

Comment: Reread the answers to your previous question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341168/how-do-i-know-which-of-these-are-mathematical-statements. This one is a description of a set of integers. It's like the set of primes. It's neither true nor false, it just is.

Comment: No. Sets are neither true nor false. Put "$7\in$" before your first line, and you get a statement.

Comment: To be a statement with true value, you will need to assert something. Right now you have asserted nothing. For example, "if $x$ is an even integer then $x = 2k$ for some integer $k$" is a true assertion.

Comment: Near duplicate + no reaction whatsoever on the previous page, these are not optimal choices.

Answer (score 2):

It is only a noun phrase.  There is no verb, so it's not a sentence.  It can't be true or false.

"Giraffes that are green"

"Giraffes that are green" is not a sentence, but a noun phrase.  It cannot be true or false.

"Giraffes that are green are more expensive than elephants." is a complete sentence.  It can be true or false.